# Trouble on `validates_inclusion_of` using radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, inclusion

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I have a problem on using the `validates_inclusion_of` method.

I my model file I have:

```
class User <  ActiveRecord::Base
  INCLUSION_VALUES = ['beautiful', 'ugly', 'good', 'bad']

  validates :test,
    :inclusion => { 
      :in => User::INCLUSION_VALUES
    }
end
```

In my view file I have

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% User::INCLUSION_VALUES.each do |test| %>
    <%= f.radio_button :test, test %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The above "view" code generate this:

```
<input type="radio" value="beautiful" name="user[test]" id="user_test_beautiful">
<input type="radio" value="ugly" name="user[test]" id="user_test_ugly">
<input type="radio" value="good" name="user[test]" id="user_test_good">
<input type="radio" value="bad" name="user[test]" id="user_test_bad">
```

Whatever I do submitting the form that gives me the validation error:

```
Test is not included in the list
```

**How can I solve the issue?**

---

I also tryed to use (as described [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_inclusion_of) in a note above the page)

```
%w(beautiful, ugly, good, bad)
```

and the `validates_inclusion_of` format

```
validates_inclusion_of :test, :in => User::INCLUSION_VALUES
```

or

```
  validates :test, :inclusion => User::INCLUSION_VALUES
```

but I get always the validation error.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION** (dho!)

I forget to make the attribute `attr_accessible`!